# duda con el uso del metodo __init__(), python

Tags: python, poo, estructuras-de-datos

es correcto este uso del metodo '**init**' cuando solo quiero dar atributos a mi clase y no requiero el uso de parametros ?

ejemplo:

```
class mamiferos:
    respirar = True
    extremidades = True

class mamiferos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.respirar = True
        self.extremidades = True
```

ambos ejemplos de codigo hacen lo mismo, cuando debo de utilizar el metodo o cuando debo crear solo los atributos ?, cual es la diferencia ?

Comment: El el primer caso los atributos definidos son de la clase. En el segundo los atributos son de la instancia una vez haya sido usada la clase para crear un objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **init** sirve para instanciar objetos con las características (parametros) que se desee, si lo dejas sin parametros siempre instanciaras un objeto sin modificar sus atributos, lo cual podrías hacer despues de instanciar el objeto y modificar sus atributos manualmente, pero ahi estarías perdiendo el concepto de uso de los objetos.